# Can Google Fit record data and send API calls when my app is closed?

Tags: android, google-fit

Can Google Fit record data and send API calls when the data is recorded even when my app is closed?

I have tried searching but no luck. It seems that I can use the Google Fit recording API but it doesn't have a callback where I can execute API calls. Do I need to use a foreground/background service for this scenario?